# Can't dual boot with Windows XP

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 into my system on a separate partition. However after the installation was successfully completed, the system keeps booting Windows XP without showing the dual boot screen. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a rather common question, people install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but Windows still boots without offering the option of Ubuntu. This is often caused by GRUB/GRUB2 (the bootloader that allows you to choose which OS to load) not being installed in the Master Boot Record (the place that tells the BIOS what to boot).

The fix usually is pretty simple, there are two relatively easy options (taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

> ## Getting Boot-Repair
>
> ### 1st option : get a CD including Boot-Repair
>
> The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following disks and boot on it.
>
> Boot-Repair-Disk is a CD starting Boot-Repair automatically.
>
> Boot-Repair is also included in Linux-Secure-Remix.
>
> Remark : you can also install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer).
>
> ### 2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu
>
> - boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
> - choose "Try Ubuntu"
> - connect internet
> - open a new Terminal, then type:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
>   update`
>
> - Press Enter.
> - Then type:
>
> `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
>
> - Press Enter

Then, once it's installed, do the following:

> ## Recommended repair
>
> ### launch Boot-Repair from either :
>
> #### the Dash
>
> (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
>
> #### or
>
> System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
>
> #### or
>
> by typing `boot-repair` in a terminal
>
> Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a
>   paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
>   If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Hope this helps!